# Type or namespace name 'UI' could not be found. c# Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, namespaces

**I am very new to c#** and have been having this problem for quite some time now, and I'm still without luck. the console says a few things but the main gist of **the problem is the **type or namespace name 'UI' could not be found.**

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.Utility
{
    [@RequireComponent(typeof(Text))]
    public class FPSCounter : MonoBehaviour
    {
        const float fpsMeasurePeriod = 0.5f;
        private int m_FpsAccumulator = 0;
        private float m_FpsNextPeriod = 0;
        private int m_CurrentFps;
        const string display = "{0} FPS";
        private Text m_UIText;


        private void Start()
        {
            m_FpsNextPeriod = Time.realtimeSinceStartup + fpsMeasurePeriod;
            m_UI.Text = GetComponent<UI.text>();
        }


        private void Update()
        {
            // measure average frames per second
            m_FpsAccumulator++;
            if (Time.realtimeSinceStartup > m_FpsNextPeriod)
            {
                m_CurrentFps = (int) (m_FpsAccumulator/fpsMeasurePeriod);
                m_FpsAccumulator = 0;
                m_FpsNextPeriod += fpsMeasurePeriod;
                m_UI.text.text = string.Format(display, m_CurrentFps);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Errors From Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/720tN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add `using UnityEngine.UI;` you are telling the script about a namespace you are going to use so you don't need to worry about using `UI.Text`, just use `Text`.

You also have a variable `m_UIText`, but when you try to assign it in the `Start` function you refer to it as `m_UI.Text`.

Simply replace the line with `m_UIText = GetComponent<Text>();`